# Can I check the Indy version installed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

I need to use the latest Indy component library version.  Can I get the library version by some source code command or any other trick to make sure I'm using the correct lib.
I know I'm using the `indy....160.bpl` - this is what my Delphi XE2 says while moving the mouse over the component bar.  The latest INDY lib I take from [Fulgan Indy](http://indy.fulgan.com/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***How to get version of Indy by using an Indy component at runtime ?***

As @Remy pointed out in his comment, you can get the Indy version from any Indy component by using the [`Version`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdBaseComponent_Version.html) property. Here's a sample using `TIdHTTP` component:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Indy version: ' + IdHTTP1.Version);
end;
```

***How to get version of Indy without an Indy component at runtime ?***

You can get the whole version string in Indy's versioning format:

```
<major>.<minor>.<release>.<build>
```

from the `gsIdVersion` constant defined in the `IdVers.inc` file included in the `IdGlobal.pas` unit in a way like follows:

```
uses
  IdGlobal;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Indy version: ' + gsIdVersion);
end;
```

or if you have Indy revision at least since 25th October 2012 (4850), you can use the individual version information elements, whose are defined in the same include file as mentioned before e.g. this way:

```
uses
  IdGlobal;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Indy version: ' +
    IntToStr(gsIdVersionMajor) + '.' +
    IntToStr(gsIdVersionMinor) + '.' +
    IntToStr(gsIdVersionRelease) + '.' +
    IntToStr(gsIdVersionBuild)
  );
end;
```

***How to get version of Indy at design time ?***

To get Indy version at design time you can simply right click any of the Indy's components dropped on a form and open its `About` box through the `About Internet Direct (Indy)...` menu item.

***Where are the version information defined ?***

As I've mentioned before, it's in the `IdVers.inc` include file stored in the `..\Lib\System\` folder of the library and it might be the next option of how to get the Indy's version information.

***Disclaimer***

Some of what was mentioned here applies to the Indy's most recent version at this time, but I'm not sure if it applies also to all older versions (such as Indy 9 for instance).

Comment: the first version works fine for me , the second solution fails because gsIdVersionMajor is not found. Should I incluse any other library

Comment: checked my inc file, the reason why version 2 does nor work, these constants are mor defined here

Comment: Now looking at the revision history, Remy added those `gsIdVersionXXX` constants on 25th October 2012, so it's quite a new thing. I'll include this information into the post.

Comment: @TLama: the `gsIdVersionXXX` defines are not defined in the public **trunk** branch of Indy 10's SVN repository. They are defined in the **DelphiNextGen** branch instead, which is not for public use yet.

Comment: @TLama: BTW, you missed an option. Instead of using `gsIdVersion` directly, every Indy component has a public `IndyVersion` property available that returns the version string (this is the same property value that the design-time About dialog shows).

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to conditionally check the Indy version at compile-time. There's a feature in newer versions of Indy, and would like to compile for multiple versions (open-source project). I found `IdVers.inc`, but this doesn't seem to define any conditionals - only constants.

Comment: Asked a new related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826276/how-to-conditionally-compile-a-newer-indy-feature

Answer (score 2):

If your application already has an instance of an Indy component (which inherits TIdBaseComponent), you can get the version simply by

```
Version := SomeIndyComponent.Version;
```

in the current version, this function will return `10.5.9.0`

Comment: `GetIndyVersion()` is the getter for the public `IndyVersion` property. Use the property, not the getter directly: `Version := SomeIndyComponent.IndyVersion;`

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the note at my post. But anyway, it's called [`Version`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdBaseComponent_Version.html), not `IndyVersion`. [+1]