# How to conditionally compile a newer Indy feature?

Tags: delphi, indy, conditional-compilation

I've already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14422904/988445) on how to check the Indy version at run-time, and there are multiple different ways. However I'm looking how to use conditionals to check the Indy version at compile-time. There's a feature in newer versions of Indy, and I want my open-source project to use this feature if it's available. But I need to conditionally compile it.

I've found `IdVers.inc`, but this file only contains constants - no version conditionals.

More specifically, the `TIdHTTP` has a property `HTTPOptions` which has a new choice `hoWantProtocolErrorContent`. If this is available, I'd like to use it.

How can I conditionally use this option if it's available?

Comment: I imagiine Remy might be able to suggest how to do this, but meanwhile you might take a look at this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/IF_directive_(Delphi) and in particular the `Declared` option.

Comment: @MartynA yes, `{$IF Declared(...)}` is the correct way to handle this, eg: `{$IF Declared(hoWantProtocolErrorContent)}` or maybe it has to be fully qualified, I don't remember : `{$IF Declared(IdHTTP.TIdHTTPOption. hoWantProtocolErrorContent)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can get the result you're wanting to achieve using the

```
{$if declared ...
```

construct.  There is an example of its usage in SysInit.Pas in the rtl:

```
function GetTlsSize: Integer;
{$IF defined(POSIX) and defined(CPUX86) and (not defined(EXTERNALLINKER))}
asm
        // Use assembler code not to include PIC base gain
        MOV  EAX, offset TlsLast
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
  Result := NativeInt(@TlsLast);
  {$IF DECLARED(TlsStart)}
  Result := Result - NativeInt(@TlsStart);
  {$ENDIF}
  [...]
```

As well as the article I mentioned in a comment, [$If Declared](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/IF_directive_(Delphi)),
 there is also this in the [D2009 online help](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsifdirective_xml.html).

`$if declared` works with methods of classes, e.g.

```
procedure TMyClass.DoSomething;
begin
  {$if declared(TMyClass.Added)}  // Added being a procedure of TMyClass
  Added;
  {$endif}
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was solved specifically using `{$IF Declared(IdHTTP.TIdHTTPOption.hoWantProtocolErrorContent)}`. And a neat trick I never knew about. This will definitely come in handy in the future. Sure beats using RTTI.